# how to move view with my finger in iphone Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, touch, swipe

i have this view that the size of him is 1280 X 345 and im moving it left and right in my screen.
now, my main question is how do i make it move with my finger (not swipeLeft / swipeRight) i want it to move with my finger like the home screen of the iPhone IOS.

now, im using this code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:infoView];
    //[self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, (location.x + self.view.frame.origin.x - dx), 0.0)];
    NSLog(@"touch: %f",location.x);

    infoView.frame = CGRectMake(infoView.frame.origin.x + location.x, 0, 1280, 345);
}
```

that should be the current **way** but i cant figur it out.
i have also try to find an answer in google and here, but, as you know.. i didn't found something useful.

i've also made this so you can understand it better.

[image]

Comment: Look into UIPageControl, that is the exact functionality it is designed to create.

Comment: What about using a UIscrollView?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i used the UIPagecontrol and UIScrollView to make it. very easy and smart object !

Answer (score 8):

Don't write code to do this yourself.  Use `UIScrollView`.  This is what it is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the same effect as the iPhone/iPad home screen you should use a UIScrollView and enable paging.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to handle it yourself for some reason, avoiding UIScrollView, there are UIGestureRecognizers, specifically UIPanGestureRecognizer which can leverage most of the job handling multiple touch events in one place.